# テキストエリアに入力されたものを結果画面に表示する方法

Tags: ruby, sinatra

ERB,paramsを使用しています。
送信フォームを作っているのですが送信内容を表示するところでエラーが起こってしまいます。
出力させる法の構文が間違っているのですがどう間違っているのかわかりません。できればご指導のほどよろしくお願いします。ちなみに全角の空白などはありませんでした。

https://i.gyazo.com/7651e90536d19d41a137fcf9756fe5a2.png
https://i.gyazo.com/d0a5690ea641f5ad50476fe72c05b69e.png

Comment: 画像は外部サイトではなく、質問の編集中にこのサイト上に直接アップロードすることをおすすめします。

Answer (score 0):

`<%=company%>`ではなく`<%=contact%>`では